# Как автоматически вносить имя авторизованного пользователя в поле модели?

Tags: python, django

Такая проблема: есть приложение для просмотра и создания новостных записей.
Появилась необходимость сохранять в БД username автора (т.е. авторизованного пользователя).
Используя [этот материал](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/models/fields.html#module-django.db.models.fields.related) подключил модель User к моей модели новостей.

Проблема заключается в том, что django не вносит имя авторизованного пользователя автоматически, а предлагает автору на выбор любое имя из существующих в User:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class NewsContent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 130)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    autor = models.ForeignKey( 'auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Я понимаю почему это работает не правильно, но мне не хватает знаний и опыта для решения проблемы.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: должен быть select? или можно просто выводить username пользователя в шаблоне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите чтобы поле `author` было автоматически установлено для текущего пользователя при создании объекта из админки зарегистрируйте `NewsContent` в `admin.py` следующим образом:

```
@admin.register(NewsContent)
class NewsContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('author',) # скрыть author поле, чтобы оно не отображалось в форме изменений

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.pk:
            obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

При создании на странице приложения аналогично убираем поле `author` для формы:

```
class NewsContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsContent
        exclude = ["date", "author"]
```

В `view` после проверки формы инициализируем атрибут `author` значением `request.user` и сохраняем объект:

```
@login_required
def makePost(request):
    form = NewsContentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.author = request.user
            new_post.save()
            return redirect('/news/')
    return render(request, 'news/makePost.html', locals())
```

Comment: Нет, мне нужно чтобы author автоматически устанавливался при создании не из админки, а с созданной мной страницы (загрузил новый скрин)

Comment: Покажите как выглядит view для этой страницы.

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
 from .forms import NewsContentForm

 # Create your views here.
 def news(request):
     return render(request,'news/news.html')
 @login_required
 def makePost(request):
     form = NewsContentForm(request.POST or None)
     if request.method == "POST":
         new_post = form.save()
         print(form.cleaned_data.get('username'))
         return redirect('/news/')
     return render(request, 'news/makePost.html',locals())

Comment: Тогда уж и форму.

Comment: from django import forms
from .models import NewsContent

class NewsContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = NewsContent
            exclude = ["date"]

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!